# Is Gazebo capable of procedural generated textures?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was wondering if one can use procedural generated textures, like the cloud feature in Blender, inside Gazebo.
Is it possible without any plugins?
Would this be possible for textures and also height map?

Update:
I found in OGRE only a plugin to use procedural generated stuff.
So I dont think it is possible but I am still not 100% sure about it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26092/is-gazebo-capable-of-procedural-generated-textures?/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm not sure but I don't think that GAZEBO is capable of that.

---

Originally posted by [morrac](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36133/morrac/) with karma: 57 on 2020-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0